# Infinite intersection of open sets need not be open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The following is the property of an open set:

The intersection of a finite number of open sets is open.

**Why is it a finite number? Why can't it be infinite?**

Comment: Because there are very easily constructible counterexamples.

Comment: Take all the open intervals containing $0\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $U_n=(-1/n,1/n)$ for $n=1,2,3,\dots$.  Then $U_n$ is open for all $n$. Suppose $x\in\cap_n U_n$.  Then if $x>0$ there is an $n$ such that $\frac1n<x$ (since $\frac1n\to0$).  Thus $x\not\in U_n$ for that $n$.   Same if $x<0$. Thus $x\not\in\cap_n U_n$.  Now $0\in U_n$ for all $n$. Thus $\cap_n U_n=\{0\}$ which is not open.

Comment: does this work if we are talking about an open set in the complex plane ?

Answer (score 3):

The key is that the intersection of infinitely many open sets may not be open. Here is an example that is easy to prove.
$$
\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(0,1+\frac1{n}\right)=(0,1]
$$